# Жизненный цикл объекта DbContext в Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository, ninject

Проблема заключается в том, что ninject создает в UnitOfWork и репозиториях разные классы DbContext, а нужно что бы репозитории пользовались контекстом UnitOfWork. Как в даном случае это можно реализовать, что бы особо не менять структуру проекта или не менять вообще.

Comment: ЗАбыл ссылку на проект: https://github.com/oTTimoshenko/InternetShop_WebApi

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения *прямо в вопросе*. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не очень понятен, но возможно вам поможет использовать unitofwork как singleton: `kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>.To<UnitOfWork>().InSingletonScope()`. Возможно тоже нужно сделать с DbContext.